# List and notifications of all SE site themes / event changes?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

Right now, there is an awesome Mass-Effect 3 event going on at [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), and an ICS contest going on at [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/).  I love participating in these events / contests (I loved the hat one on Gaming.SE around New Years).  Is there any way to get notified when a new event is coming up on one of the sites you are a member of?

Is there also a list of all the events that took place in the past?  I feel like there's a lot of cool artwork and graphic design that it would be neat to go back and look at in an archive.

UPDATE:  There is now a list of all promos at this site:
https://stackexchange.com/promos

Comment: I'm on the fence about this.  On one hand, you want people to see the cool stuff and get involved in new sites.  On the other hand, you open it up to people bouncing around and just doing stuff to try to win something.  I would suppose the former wins out but it may mean contests need to be carefully designed.

Comment: If you use RSS, you could subscribe to the feed for each site's blog that you're interested in.

Comment: @animuson yeah, except not all sites have a blog..

Comment: Is every event that has happened listed on a blog?  I think I would understand wanting to keep the events somewhat private to the frequent visitors (the sites could definitely get out of control), but would it be very difficult to find all the past events, or compile a list?  There have probably been events for sites I have never even visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a list of all promos at the following location:

https://stackexchange.com/promos

Answer (score 6):

### 2012

**Name:** Mountain Lion Challenge
**When:** July 25th 2012 - August 8th 2012
**Where:** Ask Different (Apple)
**Links:** [Meta Post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/mountain-lion-challenge-ask-answer-blog-and-win-apple-products) [Dedicated Site](http://mountainlionchallenge.com/)
**Theme Change:** Partial

**Name:** Diablo 3 Acts and Gems
**When:** May 14th 2012 - June 1st 2012
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Meta Post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4651/diablo-3-acts-and-gems-battle-the-armies-of-hell-with-us-and-earn-awesome-priz) [Dedicated Site](http://diablo3acts.com/)
**Theme Change:** Yes

**Name:** Diablo 3 is coming - train with us
**When:** April 30th 2012 - May 14th 2012
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Meta Post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/diablo-3-is-coming-train-with-us)
**Theme Change:** Minor

**Name:** Avengers vs. X-Men contest
**When:** April 4th 2012 - April 19th 2012
**Where:** Sci-Fi
**Links:** [Meta Post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/avengers-vs-x-men-scifi-event) [Dedicated Site](http://avx.stackshowdown.com/)
**Theme Change:** No

**Name:** League of Legends contest
**When:** March 17th 2012 - March 31st 2012
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Meta Post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/league-of-legends-contest)
**Theme Change:** No

**Name:** The New iPad is Here
**When:** March 16th 2012 - April 2nd 2012
**Where:** Apple
**Links:** [Meta Post](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-ipad-is-here-ask-different-and-win-one/) [Dedicated Site](http://thenewipadishere.com/)
**Theme Change:** Yes

**Name:** Game of Thrones season 1 giveaway
**When:** March 7th 2012 - March 14rd 2012
**Where:** Scifi
**Links:** [Blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-exchange-is-giving-away-sets-of-game-of-thrones-season-1-on-blu-ray-and-dvd/)
**Theme Change:** No

**Name:** Mass Effect 3: Missions
**When:** March 6th 2012 - March 23rd 2012
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/03/mass-effect-3-missions-on-gaming-se/) [Dedicated Site](http://me3missions.com/)
**Theme Change:** Yes

**Name:** Food Fight
**When:** February 27th 2012 - March 16th 2012
**Where:** Android
**Links:** [Dedicated Site](http://androidfoodfight.com/)
**Theme Change:** Yes

**Name:** Kingdoms of Amalur: A Contest
**When:** February 7th 2012 - February 17th 2012
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/02/kingdoms-of-amalur-a-contest/)
**Theme Change:** No

### 2011

**Name:** Holiday 2011 Hat Dash
**When:** December 16th 2011 - January 6th 2012
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash/) [Dedicated Site](http://hatdash.com/)
**Theme Change:** Yes

**Name:** Skyrim vs Modern Warfare 3
**When:** November 8th 2011 - November 18th 2011
**Where:** Gaming
**Links:** [Blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/11/elder-scrolls-v-vs-modern-warfare-3/) [Dedicated Site](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/)
**Theme Change:** Yes

**Name:** Super User's 2nd Birthday Super Contest
**When:** August 19th, 2011 - September 7th, 2011
**Where:** Super User
**Links:** [Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/)
**Theme Change:** No

### 2010

**Name:** Super User 1 Year Anniversary Super Contest
**When:** August 18th, 2010 - September 20th, 2010
**Where:** Super User
**Links:** [Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/)
**Theme Change:** No