# Are more contests like the Gaming/Mass Effect 3 one planned?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

So Gaming has an [Epic Mass Effect 3 contest](http://me3missions.com/) right now.

Is this something SE plans to do more with the launched SE sites? I noticed [Android also has a contest.](http://androidfoodfight.com/)

Comment: If Jeff isn't a fan of the site, endless promotions all round!

Comment: Wouldn't this be something you'd ask on the per-site Meta? In other words, isn't it the site communities that plan these things?

Comment: @CodyGray well the funding/design/domain set ups have to be from someone at Stack Exchange, in the end it depends on their willingness and drive to implement such contests, right?

Comment: Related [List and notifications of all SE site themes / event changes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124962)

Comment: @OffBySome only if you get a penalty for asking MORE questions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [List and notifications of all SE site themes / event changes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124962/list-and-notifications-of-all-se-site-themes-event-changes)

Comment: Relevant blog entry: [Hot Topics: A Contest Formula that Works](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/hot-topics-a-contest-formula-that-works/)